# Скрыть код на питоне на компьютере

Tags: python, linux

Ситуация:
Есть проект, написанный на питоне. Проект крутится на мини-компьютере, который размещается среди прочих контроллеров и устройств в шкафу. Проект коммерческий, и мы не хотим, чтобы пользователь, которому мы продадим шкаф, смог бы украсть код, либо внести туда изменения.
Вопрос, как защитить код?

У нас есть идея зашифровать весь диск SSD мини-компьютера инструментами linux. Насколько это надежно?

Comment: если у пользователя есть доступ к работающему диску, то чем поможет шифрование?

Comment: Физический доступ да. Этого разве будет достаточно? 
Т.е. если пользователь попробует просто монитор подключить, ему нужно будет пароль вводить, а если он просто снимет SSD и к себе подключит - доступа у него ни к чему не буедт, разве не так?

Comment: Если кто-то как-то будет автоматически расшифровывать диск, то значит и пользователь сможет повторить те же действия для самостоятельной расшифровки. Или кто-то будет вводить пароль вручную?

Comment: Изучайте [это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) направление

Comment: У кода есть 100% выход в глобальную сеть?

Comment: @VitaliyStop_RU_war_in_UA к сожалению, не всегда. Точнее не так - выхода в сеть может не быть, или выход может быть не стабильным, поскольку шкаф устанавливается на отдаленных промышленных объектах

Comment: закинь в докер и держи приложуху там

Comment: ну тогда прочитайте мой ответ, и отбрасывайте варианты, где нужна сеть (например на счет облачных вычислений - вам не подходит). В данном случае нет 100% правильного ответа. Вы должны почитать способы - которые есть, и выбрать для себя те - которые подойдут под проект. Если придумаете новые (или модифицируете) - это будет плюс безопасность

Comment: @Ruslan, вот тоже думали про докер, а потом подумали, не спасет ли просто шифровка диска?

Comment: @Ruslan в чем смысл использовать докер, если можно анологично использовать все прелести ОС для физической системы? запары больше - а смысл тот же. Но имеет сысл быть, т к это плюс ко вермени, если захотят поглядеть код

Comment: Просто физического доступа недостаточно, конечно. Но ведь диск же будет не просто в шкафу выключенный лежать, а в системе работать. И если у пользователя будет доступ к системе, то будет и доступ к диску.

Comment: @Ruslan а при чём тут докер, что-то помешает выковырять код программы из докера?

Comment: а у пользователя должен быть доступ к диску??? может вам подумать над хорошим замком ? xD

Comment: @Эникейщик, доступа к системе напрямую у пользователя не будет. На ПК пользователя будет десктопное приложение, которое будет обращаться к проекту по ip и порту, кидать запросы и получать ответы

Comment: @VitaliyStop_RU_war_in_UA, эту идею оставляем на самый крайний вариант ))

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и надежный способ - это скомпилировать ключевые места в сишный модуль через `cython`.

test.py:

```
print('helloword')
```

Компиляция:

```
$ cythonize -i test.py
```

Получится файлик `test.cpython-311-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`. Теперь исходники можно удалить из проекта:

```
$ rm test.py test.c
$ python -c "import test"
helloword
```

Но у пользователя остаётся возможность вызывать функции в вашем коде.

Answer (score -1):

Обфускация — это процесс преобразования исходного кода в форму, которая делает его трудночитаемым и понимаемым для человека, сохраняя при этом его функциональность. Это может быть полезно для защиты интеллектуальной собственности или для предотвращения обратного проектирования.

Вот несколько практик и инструментов для обфускации кода на Python:

1. PyArmor: Это популярный инструмент для обфускации кода Python. Он может обфусцировать часть кода или весь проект, а также поддерживает многие платформы.
2. Rename переменных и функций: Простейший способ обфускации — это переименование переменных, функций и классов в нечто неинформативное, например, из calculate_total в a1.

   Удаление комментариев и документации: Хотя это не делает код более трудным для анализа, это убирает полезную информацию, которая может помочь в понимании кода.
3. Использование строковых операций: Вы можете динамически создавать и выполнять код с помощью функций eval() и exec(). Но будьте осторожны, так как это может создать уязвимости в безопасности.
4. Упаковка кода: Существуют инструменты, такие как cx_Freeze или PyInstaller, которые позволяют упаковать ваш код в исполняемый файл. Это делает анализ исходного кода более сложным.
5. Использование компиляции: Вы можете компилировать ваш код в байт-код с помощью модуля py_compile. Это создает файл .pyc, который труднее анализировать, чем исходный код.
6. Интеграция с C/C++: Если у вас есть критические части кода, которые вы хотите защитить, вы можете реализовать их на C или C++ и вызывать из Python.
7. Обфускация строк: Строки можно кодировать и декодировать на лету, чтобы их было труднее найти и понять.
8. Использование ProGuard для Jython: Если вы используете Jython (Python для JVM), вы можете использовать инструменты обфускации Java, такие как ProGuard.
9. Избегайте обфускации стандартных библиотек: Это может вызвать проблемы совместимости.

И нужно учитывать, что обфускация не делает ваш код полностью безопасным. Она лишь затрудняет его анализ. Если кто-то действительно хочет разобраться в вашем коде, он найдет способ это сделать. Обфускация — это лишь один из инструментов в вашем арсенале защиты.

Еще несколько практик, кроме обфускации которые могут вам помочь (или на что-то надоумить, т к у многих есть много условий и "за"/"против":

1. Использование байт-кода: Python автоматически компилирует исходный код в байт-код (файлы .pyc). Хотя байт-код можно декомпилировать, это добавляет дополнительный шаг в процесс анализа.
2. Работа с лицензиями: Внедрите систему лицензирования, чтобы ограничить использование вашего продукта только лицензированными пользователями. (К примеры мы привязываемся к железу, т. к. нет выхода в сеть)
3. Тампер-детекция: Внедрите механизмы, которые определяют, был ли изменен ваш код или исполняемый файл, и предпринимают соответствующие действия (например, завершают выполнение программы).
4. Защита от отладки: Используйте методы и инструменты, которые обнаруживают попытки отладки вашего кода и прерывают выполнение или вводят злоумышленника в заблуждение.
5. Криптографическая защита: Шифруйте чувствительные данные или ключевые части кода. Также можно использовать цифровые подписи для проверки целостности кода.
6. Облачные вычисления: Если возможно, переместите критические части вашего приложения на серверную сторону. Таким образом, конечный пользователь никогда фактически не видит или не имеет доступа к этим частям кода.